# Authentication for an Azure Function app linked to an Azure Static Web App

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-static-web-app

I'm struggling a bit with setting up a function app with a static web app on Azure.

I'm making an PWA for field technicians on Static Web Apps that is backed by a Function App. I had to make a separate Function app since I needed to run it in a Premium Plan so I can get a public IP for some external services.

I want technicians and office personel to use the app via the web, but I also need to integrate a lot of the functions into other workflows and to be able to start functions both from the app and automatically from other systems on certain events.

But I can't seem to get a good setup for both authenticating users and systems/scripts.

I see the following setups:

1. Linking the SWA with the function app and setting functions authLevel to anonymous.
   Now it works perfectly for users of the app. But I can't use the functions from outside of the SWA.
   I can add an identity provider for the function app and login using the browser but that is not a smooth way to integrate other systems.
2. I can link the SWA and the function app and set the functions authLevel to function.
   Now I can use API-keys for the functions which will make it easy for other systems to use the functions. But I also need to add a function key in every api call from the SWA. Which will expose the API key in the browser and make it possible to use it to call the functions without going through the app.
3. I could set up the Function App separately and not link it to the SWA. Then using function api key I could set up managed functions in SWA that mirrors the functions I need to call.
   This would make it easy to integrate the functions to other systems via API-keys and the API key would not be exposed in the browsers since the managed function does not need it.
   But now I have double the amount of functions that I need to keep in sync.

So am I missing something? Option 3 seems like the most versatile approach but also annoying.

I would like option 1 but I don't know how I would authenticate webhooks, scripts, and other applications against the AD identity provider.

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing with the same issue and this is what I've settled on:

Per your 3), I'm not linking the Function App to the SWA.

The SWA has a custom URL so in the browser the URL routes are all branded with the nice domain.

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline that stands everything up, and it configures environment variables for the Azure Function backend to have easy access to its API Key. This is done with some PowerShell scripts. The same scripts configure the SWA's `environment.ts` file (e.g.: Function URL, MSAL AAD client Id, etc).

My initial authentication flow is for the SWA to use MSAL to AAD to get the user bearer token and id, and send that to the 'anonymous' `login()` function.  Therefore only authenticated AAD users will get a response from `login()`.  My Function code verifies the AAD user with server side MSAL. The API Key is returned after a user is authenticated and their authorisation verified.

The client app uses the Function API Key in the header for http calls to the server so that the key isn't immediately obvious I the browser.

NOTE: The API Key can still be discovered using sniffer tools, so in the Function I use another layer of security.

So solve this, after the user authenticates through the login() function, I build a JWT session token for the user and return that as a session variable to the SWA.  You are correct that all calls need to send the Function API Key header and the JWT token but in Angular this is trivial using Interceptors.

Every Function call except `login()` and various OpenAPI pages (that I serve through the Function App) then as 'function' level EasyAuth level.

To enable API integration to other 3rd parties my app just needs a page where users can create their own Personal Access Tokens (PATs).  This is the same as for any SaaS out there like GitHub, etc.  The PATs need to be put in the headers sent to the Function App and are authenticated the same was as the MSAL users (just against an application level table of hashed PATs).  The Function API Keys also need to be sent in the header as expected.

I have been looking into replacing the API integration parts with Azure API Management.  Anything but the 'Consumption' plan for APIM is prohibitively expensive for me (hence my serving up my own OpenAPI pages).  But I do plan to prototype it to see if it's worth it.  Mainly also because you can then set up nice custom URLs for the APIs also.

Having it all set up using DevOps and Infrastructure as Code really simplifies what would otherwise be complex to set up

I'd welcome thoughts, concerns, vulnerabilities and suggestions.  I hope this helps.